# old wallet.dat with only incoming tx from mining, now shows 0 coins even after rescan and all the transactions are there

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, wallet.dat

I found an old wallet.dat it contained hundreds of transactions while i was mining.

I've replaced the wallet.dat in a new Bitcoin Core wallet, rescanned, all the txid are showing but the amount of bitcoin stored there is not! It now shows 0 coins

I know i never sent them out + all the tx are inputs nothing is out, so far i tried rescan.

any idea how can i extract for example a master privat key for the entire wallet, and import it somewhere ?

Comment: Have you verified the tx ID exists on an explorer? Wallet files are often compatible across coins, you may have been mining litecoin or something else

Comment: yup, all tx are containing very small amounts (bitcoin) i used the dumpwallet command to get all public+privat keys turned out i got over 2800 transactions (my head hurts) so this command also give me an extended private masterkey (starting with: xprv) so my question is, how can i convert this extended key into simple privat key so i can sweep it into another wallte and get my coins out (if this is how it works, or maybe im wrong)

Comment: may be using  --reindex flag and adding txindex=1 in conf file solve your issue of showing 0  Coins during scanning process

Comment: @cryptoKTM this seams something worth giving a try, is there a difference if i add  -reindex flag to the end of the "Target" parameter or just -reindex ? also it appears i dont have a bitcoin.conf file. i looked everywhere since my folder is in not the default directory. What can i do to creat one so i can add thxindex=1 command

Comment: you have to create bitcoin.conf file in the data dir, by defult data directiry is 

/home/user/.bitcoin 

and 
bitcoind -daemon  --reindex
is the command to reindex it

Answer (score 1):

If you found an old wallet (prior to Core 0.13 which was released in August 2016), it wasn't using BIP32 HD. So there is very very likely no master private key,... instead, there are a large number of private keys.

You can use `dumpwallet <filename>` in the GUI console or via RPC to extract your private keys to a text file and import them into a different application.

But if you see transactions in Bitcoin Core and your balance is zero, this mostly means that there must be one or multiple spending transactions that have spent your mined bitcoins.